# django: validate count of a many to many relation before saving to database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm a little bit stuck in my django project. I want to do the following:
I have two models(unnecessary parts left out):

**models**

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
  max_users = IntegerField()
  
  @property
  def user_count(self):
    return len(self.user_set.objects.all())

class User(models.Model):
  groups = models.ManyToManyField(UserGroup)

  def clean(self):
    if self.abschnitt.count() > 2:
      return ValidationError("only two groups allowed")
```

**forms**

```
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = user
        fields = ['usergroup']
        widgets = {'usergroup': CheckboxSelectMultiple()}

    def clean_usergroup(self):
        qs = self.cleaned_data['usergroup']
        a = len(qs)
        if len(qs) > 2:
            raise ValidationError("Your group limit is 2")
        return qs
```

The UserGroups can be defined, usually there are 3 to 5 and each `UserGroup` has a maximum of users that can join it. However a user is able to join multiple groups, but he should be restricted to join 2 groups at maximum.

The user can choose his groups via a ModelForm which is generated from the `User` Model.

My approach was to override the `clean()` method of the form and the `clean_groups()` of the form, but I always ran into the problem, that when the form is reloaded I get an Exception:
`ValueError: "<User: User object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`

I know this makes sense since there isn't a saved m2m relation that can be checked against, so I rather tried to validate the form before it is saved, which unfortunately doesn't work.

here is the view, that renders the form:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid(): # <- exception occurs here or one line below
            new_user = f.save(commit=False)
            # adding some metadata to the object, not relevant for m2m, but commit = False is required for that
            return render(request, 'registration/preregister_done.html')
    else:
        f = RegisterForm()
             

    return render(request, 'register/index.html', {'form': f})
```

Is there any possibility to validate that the user doesn't check more than 2 groups without storing it in the database?

Answer (score 1):

I found a working solution:

After a little debugging I found that when calling `f.is_valid()` the model validations are also run. I added a  small verification for the pk. I changed the model verification like this:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.pk:  # <-- this was missing
        if self.usergroup.count() > 2:
            return ValidationError("only two groups allowed")
```

Now the form validation runs smoothly with f.is_valid().